# Calling model_tool_image resize on Confirm Controller

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x

i want get url link of product image

im edit catalog/controller/checkout/confirm.php

```
            $data['products'][] = array(
                'cart_id'    => $product['cart_id'],
                'product_id' => $product['product_id'],
                'name'       => $product['name'],
                'model'      => $product['model'],
                'option'     => $option_data,
                'recurring'  => $recurring,
                'quantity'   => $product['quantity'],
                'subtract'   => $product['subtract'],
                'price'      => $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($product['price'], $product['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax'))),
                'total'      => $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($product['price'], $product['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')) * $product['quantity']),
                'href'       => $this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' . $product['product_id']),
```

im try to add

```
'thumb'     => $this->model_tool_image->resize($product['image'], $this->config->get('config_image_related_width'), $this->config->get('config_image_related_height')),
```

after call $product['thumb'] in checkout/confirm.tpl
i got the Fatal Error

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function resize() on a non-object in /var/www/xxx.dev/public_html/catalog/controller/checkout/confirm.php on line 393
```

Comment: You have to load `tool/image` model on controller before call  resize function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just add

$this->load->model('tool/image');

after

$this->load->model('tool/upload');

on confirm.php controller